# AttributeError: 'Layer' object has no attribute 'listLayers'

Tags: arcpy, layers, network-analyst, python-toolbox

I want to use the result of OD cost matrix for my further calculations. However, whne I try to extract the sublayer "lines" it returnes an error

**AttributeError: 'Layer' object has no attribute 'listLayers'**

However a line before the method saveACopy (file_name) worked on the same layer file.

```
import arcpy 
import os 
def execute(self, parameters, messages):
    # Check out the Network Analyst extension license
    arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Network")

    # Set environment
    output_dir = r"D:\GISworkspace"
    arcpy.env.workspace = os.path.join(output_dir,'DataTest.gdb')  # Setting the database, where the output table will be created
    out_path = arcpy.env.workspace                                 # Variable so that it is easier to operate with the path

    #***************************************************************************

    #Set local variables
    layer_name = "ODcostMatrix"
    impedance = "Length"
    output_layer_file = os.path.join(output_dir, layer_name + ".lyrx")
    network = parameters[0].value
    nodes   = parameters[1].value

    result_object = arcpy.na.MakeODCostMatrixLayer(network, layer_name, impedance)

    #Get the layer object from the result object. The OD cost matrix layer can
    #now be referenced using the layer object.
    layer_object = result_object.getOutput(0)

    #Get the names of all the sublayers within the OD cost matrix layer.
    sublayer_names = arcpy.na.GetNAClassNames(layer_object)
    #Stores the layer names that we will use later
    origins_layer_name = sublayer_names["Origins"]
    destinations_layer_name = sublayer_names["Destinations"]

    #Load the BS locations (nodes) as both origins and destinations.
    arcpy.na.AddLocations(layer_object, origins_layer_name, nodes)
    arcpy.na.AddLocations(layer_object, destinations_layer_name,nodes)

    #Solve the OD cost matrix layer
    arcpy.na.Solve(layer_object)

    #Save the solved OD cost matrix layer as a layer file on disk
    layer_object.saveACopy(output_layer_file)

    #Get the Lines Sublayer (all the distances) TODO fix the Atrribute Error: no method listLayers
layer_object.listLayers(sublayer_names["ODLines"])[0]
```

Comment: `ListLayers` is a [function, not a class method](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-a-method-and-function-in-Python).  You have to pass in a `MapDocument` into `ListLayers`.

Comment: Honestly, I have copied it from http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/network-analyst/make-od-cost-matrix-layer.htm and other than this line everything works fine. I have checked that there is this sublayer, I can see it in the saved file.

Comment: Generally, I want to get to the attribute table of the Lines sublayer in ODcostmatrix results. If there is a better way, I would be happy to know about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After being reasonably pointed out to the shortage of my knowledge, I have conducted some further research. Now, it works with the following solution:

```
lines_layer_name = sublayer_names["ODLines"]
lines_sublayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(layer_object, lines_layer_name)[0]
```

More reading on this can be done at [ArcGIS help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Make_Route_Layer/00480000000n000000/)

Answer (score 3):

You are receiving this error for the reason @crmackey provided in a comment:

> ListLayers is a function, not a class method. You have to pass in a
>   MapDocument into ListLayers.

His comment is based on you using ArcPy with the ArcGIS 10.x architecture.  On the other hand you are reading [documentation from ArcGIS Pro](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/network-analyst/make-od-cost-matrix-layer.htm) and appear to be assuming that the ArcPy imported from Desktop and Pro are identical when they clearly are not (see [Terminology for distinguishing ArcPy installed with ArcGIS 10.x for Desktop from that which comes with ArcGIS Pro?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172856/terminology-for-distinguishing-arcpy-installed-with-arcgis-10-x-for-desktop-from)).

I have not worked with Network Analyst for quite a while, and perhaps never with `arcpy.na`, but I think the [ODCostMatrixSolverProperties (arcpy.na)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01mr0000000r000000) page may be a good place to start getting back on track:

> Provides access to analysis properties from an origin-destination (OD)
>   cost matrix network analysis layer. The GetSolverProperties function
>   is used to obtain an ODCostMatrixSolverProperties object from an OD
>   cost matrix network analysis layer.

Comment: Thank you! It gave me a good starting option for the search. Now it works.